# Xamarin Forms from Windows Phone 8.1(RT) - xaml exceptions

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, win-universal-app

I created app with Xamarin Forms for Windows Phone 8.1(RT). I updated XF to last version 2.3.4.231. My app in run to:

-windows phone 8.1 device

-windows phone 8.1 emulator

-mobile emulator 10.0.14393(x86)

It work is  ok.
But when I running app to Windows 10 device(arm) I have many exception. I try different start pages and get mane exceptions(from xaml):

```
-Cannot assign property \"ColumnDefinitions\": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property"

-StaticResource not found for key ...

-An item with the same key has already been added
```

All these errors are related to xaml. 
I do not use XamlCompilationOptions.Compile.

Last working version XF for my app 2.3.2.127

This small example:
I changed start page. I have exception:

```
-StaticResource not found for key StandardPadding
```

This is part of my page:

```
 <StackLayout  Padding="{StaticResource StandardPadding}">
```

My resource in App.xaml:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Thickness x:Key="StandardPadding">16</Thickness>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Can you share your XAML code?

Comment: I added little example in my question

Comment: ColumnDefinitions is a part of Grid (basically, Grid.ColumnDefinitions) - you need to provide the XAML for your entire page in order for us to see what is wrong with it - not just a small snippet.

Comment: It's not a problem my xaml. This is problem my project and Xamarin Forms(2.3.4.231). My code working in emulators(8.1 and 10) and not working in Windows 10 device (arm).When I make downgrade to XF 2.3.2.127 my code working in Windows 10 device.

Comment: May be you forgot to call `InitializeComponent();` in your app.xaml.cs?

Comment: no, This is in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The error was in my xaml code. Xamarin Forms 2.3 not supported Windows OnPlatform in xaml. So I used this extension:

```
public class XOnPlatform<T> : OnPlatform<T>
{
    public T Windows { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(XOnPlatform<T> onPlatform)
    {
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows)
        {
            return onPlatform.Windows;
        }

        return (OnPlatform<T>)onPlatform;
    }
}
```

I used this class in my xaml code. But in XF 2.3.4 Device.OS is obsolete. I removed XOnPlatform from my  xaml code. I use OnPlatform in my xaml code.This is work. Bingo :)